# ClassValue in Java 7

Tags: java, java-7

While browsing the Java 7 API documentation I stumbled upon the new class [java.lang.ClassValue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassValue.html) with the following rather minimal documentation:

> Lazily associate a computed value with (potentially) every type. For example, if a dynamic language needs to construct a message dispatch table for each class encountered at a message send call site, it can use a `ClassValue` to cache information needed to perform the message send quickly, for each class encountered.

Can anyone give a better explanation of what problem this class solves and perhaps some sample code or open source project that already uses this class?

**Update:** I'm still interested in some actual source code or examples using this new class.

I also found [this mail on the mlvm-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/mlvm-dev/2011-September/003930.html) concerning some implementation improvements. It was apparently changed from using a WeakHashMap to a new private field on java.lang.Class to make it more scalable.

Comment: Reading the API you linked to suggests to me that the `get()` method is the the best place for clues. I don't understand why the `get()` method is given a `Class` object, however.

Comment: There is currently a discussion on the core-libs mailing list (http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/mlvm-dev/2013-April/005321.html) regarding usage of ClassValue in groovy and its interactions with class unloading.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best explanation of the purpose of this class is that it solves [Java Bug 6389107](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6389107)

There are many use cases where one wants to essentially have a `Map<Class<?>, T>` for some reason, but this causes all sorts of trouble since `Class` objects will then not be GC-able until the Map is.  `WeakHashMap<Class<?>, T>` doesn't solve the problem because very frequently, `T` references the class.

The bug above goes into a much more detailed explanation and contains example projects/code that face this problem.

ClassValue is the answer to this problem.  A thread-safe, classloader loading/unloading safe way to associate data with a Class.

Comment: Does this imply that most situations that want `Class->T` should use `ClassValue`? I've found myself implementing a *SERVICE REGISTRY* and other use-cases where it's pretty common to want to group a class with  its implementers or other related types.

Answer (score 7):

Its purpose it to allow adding runtime information to arbitrary target classes ([reference](http://www.wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/Why_Interface_Injection)).

I think its targeted more towards dynamic language programmers. I am not sure how it will be useful for general application developers though.

Initially the class was there in the package `java.dyn`. [This bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7012648) shows it moving to java.lang.

Comment: first link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

`ClassValue` cache something about the class.

Here is a part of code (at Lucene 5.0  `AttributeSource.java`):

```
/** a cache that stores all interfaces for known implementation classes for performance (slow reflection) */
private static final ClassValue<Class<? extends Attribute>[]> implInterfaces = new ClassValue<Class<? extends Attribute>[]>() {
    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Attribute>[] computeValue(Class<?> clazz) {
      final Set<Class<? extends Attribute>> intfSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
      // find all interfaces that this attribute instance implements
      // and that extend the Attribute interface
      do {
        for (Class<?> curInterface : clazz.getInterfaces()) {
          if (curInterface != Attribute.class && Attribute.class.isAssignableFrom(curInterface)) {
            intfSet.add(curInterface.asSubclass(Attribute.class));
          }
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
      } while (clazz != null);
      @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"}) final Class<? extends Attribute>[] a =
          intfSet.toArray(new Class[intfSet.size()]);
      return a;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is an abstract class. I've found a [copy](http://basic-jdk.jsr308-langtools.googlecode.com/hg/src/share/classes/java/lang/ClassValue.java). Have a look at it.

Comment: Here's a [syntax-highlighted](http://code.google.com/p/jsr308-langtools/source/browse/src/share/classes/java/lang/ClassValue.java?repo=basic-jdk) copy.